# phpMyAdmin message "Import has been successfully finished, 9 queries executed." No rows updated

Tags: php, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

When I try and import a CSV file to a table in phpMyAdmin it says

> Import has been successfully finished, 9 queries executed.

However, when I go to that table there is no data in it. I found that when I type the values into Excel and save it as a CSV and then upload it, it works fine. But when I try to copy and paste information into Excel and save it as a CSV, I get the issue where it tells me it is successful, but nothing is actually inserted.

What could be the problem here?

```
Test excel sheet 1 (typed in):
Report  Sheet   Decision    Linker_EID  ACCT_ID PLSTC_NUM   CUST_ST Region  EVT_DT  Relevent_ID_NUM Injection_dt    Status_ts
ID  ATO EMAIL           1243114324  9511    TX      7/4/2015    xxx@yopmail.com 8/5/2015    
ID  ATO EMAIL           12412341234 3456    CA      7/5/2015    xxx@yopmail.com 8/6/2015    
ID  ATO EMAIL           123431432 1593  MD      7/6/2015    xxx@yopmail.com 8/7/2015    
ID  ATO EMAIL           124314414 9657  VA      7/7/2015    xxx@yopmail.com 8/8/2015    

Test excel sheet 2 (copy and paste): Test excel sheet 1:
Report  Sheet   Decision    Linker_EID  ACCT_ID PLSTC_NUM   CUST_ST Region  EVT_DT  Relevent_ID_NUM Injection_dt    Status_ts
ID  ATO EMAIL           1243114324  9511    TX      7/4/2015    xxx@yopmail.com 8/5/2015    
ID  ATO EMAIL           12412341234 3456    CA      7/5/2015    xxx@yopmail.com 8/6/2015    
ID  ATO EMAIL           123431432 1593  MD      7/6/2015    xxx@yopmail.com 8/7/2015    
ID  ATO EMAIL           124314414 9657  VA      7/7/2015    xxx@yopmail.com 8/8/2015
```

Comment: Have you compared the contents of the two CSV files?  Add them to the question and we can have a look.

Comment: How do you add the files themselves? I can do a screenshot of what it looks like if that will be enough?

Comment: I would just cut/paste the text into the question.  Make sure you format it as "code" by highlighting it and press the toolbar button for "code."  If it's really long, just take the first few lines from each file.